# How can i vertically align columns in a table using liquid

Tags: html, css, liquid

i have been browsing here for probably 10 years, dont know how it took this long to make an account to ask my own question. Here it is:

I have the following liquid code:

```
<table data-mce-fragment="1" width="100%">
<td data-mce-fragment="1" style="width: 50%;">{{ 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0556/5258/1539/files/windows-logo.png'| img_tag: 'Windows Compatible Operating Systems' }} Windows Compatible Operating Systems<br><br>
{{ product.metafields.custom.windows_compatible_operating_systems_3_0 }}</td>
<td data-mce-fragment="1" style="width: 50%;">{{ 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0556/5258/1539/files/mac-logo.png?v=1707807667'| img_tag: 'Mac Compatible Operating Systems' }} Mac Compatible Operating Systems<br><br>
{{ product.metafields.custom.mac_compatible_operating_systems_3_0 }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It is outputting like my attached image.

It is vertically unaligned.

Question is, how can I get the windows column vertically align to top with the mac column?

Im assuming Mac column is higher up due to longer text.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy6ut.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know liquid Library, but you can use the below solution when your application only works on web browser.

Use `vertical-align` options for each `td` tag. `vertical-align` option might work if you didn't change `td` tag's display property.

(documentation for vertical-align, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

```
<body>
  <table data-mce-fragment="1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td
          data-mce-fragment="1"
          style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top"
        >{{ 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0556/5258/1539/files/windows-logo.png'| img_tag: 'Windows Compatible Operating Systems' }} Windows Compatible Operating Systems<br><br>
        {{ product.metafields.custom.windows_compatible_operating_systems_3_0 }}
        </td>
        
        <td
          data-mce-fragment="1"
          style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top"
        >{{ 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0556/5258/1539/files/mac-logo.png?v=1707807667'| img_tag: 'Mac Compatible Operating Systems' }} Mac Compatible Operating Systems<br><br>
        {{ product.metafields.custom.mac_compatible_operating_systems_3_0 }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```